# What is this picker component called in the context of Android? (Dual List)

Tags: android, user-experience

I am creating a View and was looking for Android Material Design Guidelines for the type of component shown in the image below - but I have no idea what it is called. In UX what is the name for the component I have marked with a red square?

(The component being where you have lists of items on the left and right with buttons or drag/drop functionality to move items between them)

I had a search on Android-Arsenal, but I didn't find anything that gave me a clue

**Note: the picture is for illustration** (I know what it *does* but not what it is *called*)

[image]

Comment: You're right. It does not say that and I misinterpreted that part. I can also see how my first comment can come across as sarcasm but the aggressive manner in which you reply is uncalled for

Comment: Anyway, this component (or similar) is not represented in the material design specs or other official specs, so it is unlikely you will find an name for it in the context of android. You will have to find inspiration in other material components for a custom design/implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java I've seen it called a Dual List Box, in GXT it's called a Dual List Field.  I looked around and can't find any reference to it in Android.

Answer (score 0):

These are some suggested component for your resource file.
You can choose one or more item for your resource file. Your chosen components will show on the right side.

Comment: Thanks Aziz but that's not the question - I want to know the name of this type of layout - where you select things from one column to the other. The picture is just an illustration